# Android Canvas onDraw problems when onResume

Tags: java, android, canvas, oncreate, onresume

i have one little problem with the **canvas in android**.
I am programming a scanner.
The function of the scanner works perfectly.
But my goal is it to **draw some rectangles into the scanner**, that it looks like a real scanner.
That works half the time.

**If I start the App the first time, it is all fine. All rectangles and the scanner lines is drawn in the middle.
But if I close the App and restart it, the rectangles and the line is missing**.

**I have the method onDraw, and I know that the app is calling it (in both times)**.
I have checked all variables (case: first start, restart).
If I power off my device and start the app new it works too.

*Maybe do I have to bring the elements to the front?*

Thanks.

```
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        setWillNotDraw(false);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (cameraManager == null) {
            return; // not ready yet, early draw before done configuring
        }
        Rect frame = cameraManager.getFramingRect();
        Rect previewFrame = cameraManager.getFramingRectInPreview();

        if (frame == null || previewFrame == null) {
            return;
        }
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();

        // Draw the exterior (i.e. outside the framing rect) darkened
        paint.setColor(resultBitmap != null ? resultColor : maskColor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, frame.top, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, frame.top, frame.left, frame.bottom + 1, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(frame.right + 1, frame.top, width, frame.bottom + 1,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, frame.bottom + 1, width, height, paint);


        if (resultBitmap != null) {
            // Draw the opaque result bitmap over the scanning rectangle
            paint.setAlpha(CURRENT_POINT_OPACITY);
            canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, null, frame, paint);
        } else {

            // Draw a red "laser scanner" line through the middle to show
            // decoding is active
            paint.setColor(laserColor);
            paint.setAlpha(SCANNER_ALPHA[scannerAlpha]);
            scannerAlpha = (scannerAlpha + 1) % SCANNER_ALPHA.length;
            int middle = frame.height() / 2 + frame.top;
            canvas.drawRect(frame.left + 2, middle - 1, frame.right - 1,
                    middle + 2, paint);



            float scaleX = frame.width() / (float) previewFrame.width();
            float scaleY = frame.height() / (float) previewFrame.height();

            List<ResultPoint> currentPossible = possibleResultPoints;
            List<ResultPoint> currentLast = lastPossibleResultPoints;
            int frameLeft = frame.left;
            int frameTop = frame.top;
            if (currentPossible.isEmpty()) {
                lastPossibleResultPoints = null;
            } else {
                possibleResultPoints = new ArrayList<ResultPoint>(5);
                lastPossibleResultPoints = currentPossible;
                paint.setAlpha(CURRENT_POINT_OPACITY);
                paint.setColor(resultPointColor);
                synchronized (currentPossible) {
                    for (ResultPoint point : currentPossible) {
                        canvas.drawCircle(frameLeft
                                + (int) (point.getX() * scaleX), frameTop
                                + (int) (point.getY() * scaleY), POINT_SIZE,
                                paint);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (currentLast != null) {
                paint.setAlpha(CURRENT_POINT_OPACITY / 2);
                paint.setColor(resultPointColor);
                synchronized (currentLast) {
                    float radius = POINT_SIZE / 2.0f;
                    for (ResultPoint point : currentLast) {
                        canvas.drawCircle(frameLeft
                                + (int) (point.getX() * scaleX), frameTop
                                + (int) (point.getY() * scaleY), radius, paint);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Request another update at the animation interval, but only
            // repaint the laser line,
            // not the entire viewfinder mask.
            postInvalidateDelayed(ANIMATION_DELAY, frame.left - POINT_SIZE,
                    frame.top - POINT_SIZE, frame.right + POINT_SIZE,
                    frame.bottom + POINT_SIZE);
        }




    }
```

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the camera.

If you close the app the lifecycle of your app/mainActivity is repeated the same from the beginning (if you do not have some background service).

The only memories that a new execution can have of a previous one is if you didn't released the camera resources properly in your onPause() or onStop() or OnDestroy() etc...

did you  called something like

```
   if(camera!=null){
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
```

in OnDestroy() method of the activity that holds the camera 
or in surfaceDestroyed() if you are using your surfaceView?

Comment: Code is posted.. And yes I use the camera

Comment: Well, I just have a surfaceDestroyed method, but when is the actual call of this method. When i leave the method? Or wenn the app is actually destroyed?
I just have a surfaceChanged. 

Do I have to put your code into my MainActivity or into the CameraActivity or into the Surface Activity?

I just have a SurfaceHolder?! Is this useful?

And I have a CameraManager.

Comment: Just tried, but didn't solved the problem.
And my cameraManager don't have setPreviewCallback and don't have release().

Comment: Could it be that the problem is, that the methods surfaceCreated or surfaceChanged never called? And in the Log i can see the debug message 'app passed NULL surface' ?